# How can you have a variable be edited by an event created in a different object?

Tags: java, object, actionlistener

Here is some example code that has 2 objects. A panel object to easily create panels and listeners, and a frame object to execute code. The intention is to get the code to display which button was pressed in answertext field. However, I do not see a way I can get it to compile as wherever I make answertext is outside the scope of something else I need.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;



class myPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {

public myPanel(int start, int numOfButtons){

    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));

    JButton buttons[] = new JButton[numOfButtons];

    for (int k = start; k < start + numOfButtons; k++){


            buttons[ k ] = new JButton("Button " + k);
            this.add( buttons[k] );
            buttons[ k ].addActionListener(this); 
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    myFrame.setText(e.getActionCommand()); 
}

}


public class myFrame extends JFrame{



public myFrame()
{

super("myFrame");



myPanel buttonPanel1 =  new myPanel(1, 3);
myPanel buttonPanel2 =  new myPanel(4, 3);

JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel();

JTextField answertext;
answertext = new JTextField(10);
answertext.setEditable(false);
answerPanel.add(answertext);



setSize(300,200);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLayout( new GridLayout(3,1) );
setTitle("ShowPressedButton");

add(buttonPanel1);
add(answerPanel);       
add(buttonPanel2);

pack();
setVisible(true);   
}


public void setText(string input)
{
    answertext = input;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    myFrame showButton = new myFrame();

    showButton.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

}




}
```

I put a public method to set the answertext so that mypanel could set it, however the compiler says that it cannot find that method when I try to compile

Answer (score 0):

Implement this function in your mypanel class

```
public JTextField get(){
  return answerText;
}
```

Then inside  myframe, call the above method using a your mypanel class object

Answer (score 0):

add some variable to myPanel Class

```
class myPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   private List<ActionListener> actionListeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

   public myPanel(final int start, final int numOfButtons) {
     // same code 
   }

   public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
     for (final ActionListener listener : actionListeners) {
       listener.actionPerformed(e);
     }
   } 

   public void addActionListener(final ActionListener listener) {
     actionListeners.add(listener)
   } 
   // todo: remove / reset ActionListener ...
}
```

After this you can add an ActionListener in your class myFrame witch knows the JTextfield and can manipulate it. After adding this new ActionListener to the myPanel frame you should know which button is pressed